# Что делает данный PHP код?

Tags: php

Только начинаю изучать `PHP`. Вопрос: Почему условие срабатывает и код выводит строки `$value1 и $value2`. Если `$value == 0` то вывести все `$value`, но там же нет 0. Почему он выводит их?

```
$items = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
];

foreach($items as $key => $value) {
    if((int)$value == 0) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//  Думаю с массивом все понятно
$items = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
];

foreach($items as $key => $value) { //  Пробегаемся по нашему массиву
// Будет 2 иттерации, где:
// 1) $key = key1; $value = value1
// 2) $key = key2; $value = value2
    if((int)$value == 0) {  //  Приводим строку к int и сравниваем результат с 0
        echo $value;    // Если верно, то выводим $value
    }
}
```

Теперь по поводу `(int)$value`, `$value` - у вас строка, вы пытаетесь строку переделать в числовой тип. если у вас там символы, то в числа их перевести не получится, выдается 0, примеры:

```
var_dump((int)'text'); // 0
var_dump((int)'123'); // 123
var_dump((int)'5.15'); // 5
```

**Однако**

```
var_dump((int)'8text'); // 8
```

---

И документация: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php

Конкретно нас интересует: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

> Значение определяется по начальной части строки. Если строка
>   начинается с верного числового значения, будет использовано это
>   значение. Иначе значением будет 0 (ноль). Верное числовое значение -
>   это одна или более цифр (могущих содержать десятичную точку), по
>   желанию предваренных знаком, с последующим необязательным показателем
>   степени. Показатель степени - это 'e' или 'E' с последующими одной или
>   более цифрами.

и там ниже примеры.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

Из-за преобразования (int). Поскольку текстовое значение value... не является числом, то приведение к целому возвращает 0

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!